# Vue v-model targeting other elements within the v-for loop -- how to construct the v-model array structure to avoid this

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

Summary: My v-model input affects other elements in the same array but I expect it to just target the input I am amending.

In my Vue data store I have an array userAnswers of 2 objects (0 and 1). This is constructed on created created()  *(mentioning in case this is relevant).*

You can see an the structure of the data here:

```
userAnswers:Array[2]
  0:Object
     answers:Object
       1:"3"
       10:"3"
       13:"3"
       15:"99"
       18:"3"
      id:4
   1:Object
     answers:Object
       1:"3"
       10:"3"
       13:"3"
       15:"99"
       18:"3"
      id:3
```

In this example I have question IDs 1,10,13 etc. and I have used the following v-model wrapped in a v-for loop to produce two inputs.

```
<div v-for="(group, key) in selectedAssessment.questions" :key="key">
 <div
     v-for="(participant, i) in participants"
     v-bind:key="participant.id"
 >
     <input type="text" v-model="form['userAnswers'][1]['answers'][question.id]" />
 </div>
</div>
```

This loops over the questions and then within that loop creates an input for each user. When I change the input for a user it is bound to both inputs within the question loop when I am expecting the v-model just to target the specific user question id.

Is there something I missing with my v-model="" reference that causes this?

Screenshot included for some clarity.

**UPDATE:**

As per recommendation I have created a jsfiddle and isolated the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/raisonon/jf5t460s/44/

I am constructing the data object on created() and this causes the issue. I'm not sure why though.

```
  created() {
  
        
    // Form Answers -- Add empty answers arr
         this.form.userAnswers = this.form.userAnswers.map((el) => {
            var o = Object.assign({}, el);
            o.answers =  this.questionIds;
            return o;
        }, this.questionIds);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Very strange -- I have it working perfectly using the above code in jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/raisonon/jf5t460s/37/) and this is with me just declaring  the data... So that has narrowed the issue..

In my vue I have quite a complex setup, whereby on created() I'm building my data object. 

I've edited the above question to include my created() {} perhaps that is why v-model doesn't behave...

Comment: Update to say more fiddling in jsfiddle and I have replicated the issue and pinpointed it to the created() method -- updated above with more details too

Comment: That's really odd, at first I thought it was because `question.id` was the same for both inputs but, looking closer, they're separate objects, so, how they can be v-modelled to both at once is strange